# How to find child ref of nested refs tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

Please find the refs tree on below image, here I need to get `rememberMe(as highlighted in the image below)`. Depth ids dynamic also in between parent refs value also dynamic. Here I could use recursive methods & for loops to find `rememberMe` but I want to know any optimal solution here.

Is there any function available to get the inner child by key value of the nested object/refs tree?

[image: Nested Refs object tree]

Comment: How are your React components stacked? Could you paste that code?

Comment: I can't help but think that this is a bad idea. What problem are you trying to solve? There's probably a better way.